# form disable button if edit-Text is null(empty)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

i need help i made this form that sends user text data into Firebase-real-time database by a button and few edit-text but i need some form security so that users can't just enter blank data i have tried but can't get it to work i do need help just like a button disable or alert that tells the user to enter some text
best regards.

xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:background="#F9B101"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Buyers page"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
         />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:id="@+id/address"

        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
         />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="phone number"
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
         />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="email address"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/order"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="order"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#F9B101"
        android:textColor="#696969"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private EditText name,address,phoneNumber,email;
    private Button order;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        

        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        address = findViewById(R.id.address);
        phoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        order = findViewById(R.id.order); //button


        order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name",name.getText().toString());
                map.put("address",address.getText().toString());
                map.put("phoneNumber",phoneNumber.getText().toString());
                map.put("email",email.getText().toString());

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders").push()
                        .setValue(map)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Order is processing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SuccessActivity.class));
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Order Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    // Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
    private void showSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `setEnabled` property of button to enable/disable it based on the input. And you can add a textChangeListener to your edittext where you check the input validity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the text field is empty, then just show a toast like this:

```
if(name.getText().toString().equals(""){
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Enter Your Name",
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 else{
 //Send the name
 }
```

You can also disable the button if the name filed is empty, but I think it is better to show a toast so that the user knows what to do. It's just more userfriendly.
For any reason if you would like to disable the button you can use this code in your if clause:

```
yourButton.setEnabled(false); // yourButton is the name of your button!
```

Comment: can you help me disable the button as i would like it more that way?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the edit text data is empty or not by checking

```
if(name.getText().toString()!="")
```

In this way you can show a popup on else part saying that the fields are empty.